# Creating a loop for Scanner for arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a loop that asks for the Scanner to input each number one after the another for a certain amount in an array (I'm thinking of 10). Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignSeven 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] array1 = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = a;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're only asking for input once.

Comment: it should be `array1[i] = sc.nextInt();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        array1[i] = a;
    }
```

or even

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you can just assign the value of the scanner object's input to the indices of the array:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignSeven 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] array1 = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Where you had the original input
        // int a = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            // Instead of array1[i] = a; you have
            array1[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helped!